Data changes taking a long time to show/update when using Excel as Data source in Power Apps
I have a Power Apps with an Excel file as a data source. The Excel file has about 75,000 rows of data in it. The data inside the excel file are user emails (each one is a unique email) and various other data related to that user.
The first page of the power app is a form. There are few fields to be filled and we click submit. These fields and submit button is only available if this is the first time we are submitting the form (The submit button and fields are not visible if we have already submitted the form before).
It moves to an another page where it shows "form has been submitted". I have inserted this power app in a SharePoint site page. Now, the issue I am facing is that after submitting the form (for the first time) it moves to the "form has been submitted" screen.
But if we reload the page, we move back to the first page but we can still submit the form. The fields and the submit form should not be visible since we have already submitted the form. I believe this is because the excel file and the power app is not getting updated instantaneously.
I checked the excel after submitting the form and the data is getting updated pretty quickly(less than 30 seconds). But it takes about 4 to 5 minutes before the required screen where the submit and field are invisible is showing in the power app. I believe the issue is because I am using Excel with lot of entries as data source. It there a way to make and show all the data change instantaneous?

In Power Apps, where are you checking if form is already submitted by user when you open the app (or reload the page)?

Since I have added the powerapp to a sitepage. I am checking if the form is submitted by reloading the sitepage. But only it shows the values have been submitted only after a 4-5 minute delay.

You must be having some logic/formulas "inside" the power app to check if user already submitted the for or not --> I am asking about that, where have you added that formula to check?

Ive added that is a particular datacardvalue is true then the form will be in view and the submit button will be hidden. The value inside the datacard will become true after submitting the form
If(
DataCardValue25.Text="True",
FormMode.View,
FormMode.Edit
)

What is the formula written in Text property of DataCardValue25 control?
